# Cannot retrieve categories for post in The Loop

Tags: terms, title

```php
add_filter('the_title', 'filter_title_add_post_category');
function filter_title_add_post_category($title) {
    global $post;
    
    $debug = '';
    
    if (
        is_single()
        && in_the_loop()
    ) {
        $post_categories = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'category');
        
        $debug = print_r($post_categories, true) . $post->ID;
        
        if(!empty($post_categories)) {
            $title_prefix = '<span class="title-category">';
            $title_prefix .= esc_html($post_categories[0]->name);
            $title_prefix .= ' &gt; </span>';

            $title = $title_prefix . $title;
        }
    }
    
    return $title . '<!-- ' . $debug . ' -->';
}
```

On a single post with catégories I get this:

```html
<!-- 123456789 -->
```

Comment: Are you sure you're `in_the_loop()` when you're getting the title? In a single-post template you might not be. (Also, the [`the_title` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_title/) receives the current post ID as a second parameter, so you don't necessarily need the `global $post;` (though I doubt it's hurting anything).)

Comment: `is_single() && in_the_loop()` fire as the debug displays the postID, the issue I have is that `get_the_terms()` or `get_the_category()` returns nothing !!!!

Comment: @AntonyGibbs If you change the `print_r` to `var_export`, and use `get_the_ID()` instead, i.e. `get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category')` and `var_export($post_categories, true)`, what's the output? Are you sure you're looking at the correct title element/area?

Comment: Are you sure that `category` is the correct taxonomy? If you're using a custom post type it might have its own taxonomy. For example, WooCommerce has a `product_cat` taxonomy.

Comment: I tried your code verbatim on a local test installation, and it worked as expected —ie, the title became `First Category > Post Title`. Assuming you're dealing with a `post` post type and the `category` taxonomy, I don't see why this wouldn't work. Have you tried disabling other plugins and using a default theme?